# How to redirect an accepted call in Twilio to an another worker?

Tags: twilio

I use Twilio and want to make call center. I use the TaskRouter and VoiceAPI but I didn't find the way to redirect accepted call to an another specialist. For example, if a manager after a couple of minutes of a conversation wants to connect a client to specialist from the support service. Can I do this in using Twilio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andrew here is a perfect [example](https://github.com/vernig/twilio-taskrouter-agent-frontend) for your use case. It worked for me. Do try it and if there is any question let me know in the comments. I will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are some sequence diagrams below that should help.

[Call Control Concepts](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/contact-center-blueprint/call-control-concepts)

[Call Control Concepts | Appendix | Web Sequence Diagrams](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/contact-center-blueprint/call-control-concepts-web-sequence-diagrams)